# Why is the free space in a storage pool less than the capacity?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, storage

I'm trying to set up a new storage pool using 2 physical disks in my system. The sceneario is as follows:

I have 2x 3TB HDDS in the machine. The machine's BIOS doesn't support booting from GPT :( therefore disk 0 is MBR and disk 1 is GPT.

After installing windows on it's own partition of approx 120gb, I want to pool the remaining allocatable space from disk 0 with all the space on disk 1.

I've created my storage pool with a reported capacity and free space of 4.61TB. However when I try and create a virtual disk, I cannot create one that uses all of this space. See below:

[image]

After creating this virtual disk, I can create a second virtual disk with the remaining 800some gig space from the pool.

Why is this?

Comment: It seems after creating the 2 disks, as a work around I can then use disk manager to create a new spanned volume. Seems a bit of a bodge job setup lol

Comment: Feel to me a 4TB limit somewhere...